# SQL Query some assistance needed in fixing query so it returns a row per Unique ID

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am in need of help fixing a query so it returns the right number of rows. I have the table below with 12 rows per ProductID in it. What I would like is to turn these 12 rows to 1 row with 12 set columns for each Product ID.

the generated dynamic code only creates 1 row

```
--Table this belongs to 

   Create table #Attributes
    (
            ProductID uniqueIdentifier,
            PAID Varchar(48), 
            Label nvarchar(50),
            AttrValue nvarchar(3072),
            unit nvarchar(50) 
    )
 . . . . . . .

select *
      from
      (
        select col + cast(rn as varchar(10)) new_col, val
        from 
        (
          select 
          Cast(PAID as NVarchar(3072)) PAID
          ,Cast (ProductID as NVarchar(3072)) ProductID
           ,Cast (Label  as NVarchar(3072)) Label
           ,Cast (Value as NVarchar(3072)) Value
           ,Cast (unit as NVarchar(3072))  unit  
            ,row_number() over(partition by ProductID order by ProductID) rn
          from #Attributes
        ) x
        unpivot
        (
          val
          for col in ([ProductID],[PAID],[Label],[Value],[unit])
        ) u
      ) x1
      pivot
      (
        max(val)
        for new_col in
          ([ProductID1],[PAID1],[Label1],[Value1],[unit1],[ProductID2],[PAID2],[Label2],[Value2],[unit2],[ProductID3],[PAID3],[Label3],[Value3],[unit3],[ProductID4],[PAID4],[Label4],[Value4],[unit4],[ProductID5],[PAID5],[Label5],[Value5],[unit5],[ProductID6],[PAID6],[Label6],[Value6],[unit6],[ProductID7],[PAID7],[Label7],[Value7],[unit7],[ProductID8],[PAID8],[Label8],[Value8],[unit8],[ProductID9],[PAID9],[Label9],[Value9],[unit9],[ProductID10],[PAID10],[Label10],[Value10],[unit10],[ProductID11],[PAID11],[Label11],[Value11],[unit11],[ProductID12],[PAID12],[Label12],[Value12],[unit12],[ProductID13],[PAID13],[Label13],[Value13],[unit13],[ProductID14],[PAID14],[Label14],[Value14],[unit14],[ProductID15],[PAID15],[Label15],[Value15],[unit15],[ProductID16],[PAID16],[Label16],[Value16],[unit16],[ProductID17],[PAID17],[Label17],[Value17],[unit17],[ProductID18],[PAID18],[Label18],[Value18],[unit18],[ProductID19],[PAID19],[Label19],[Value19],[unit19],[ProductID20],[PAID20],[Label20],[Value20],[unit20],[ProductID21],[PAID21],[Label21],[Value21],[unit21])
      ) p
```

The current code, only generates 1 row of data and ignores other ProductID's in my table. I would appreciate some help to fix this issue. Thanks.

BELOW here is a table(think Excel without the column dividing lines. The Product ID field has values but there are no values in the PAID, LABEL, VALUE and UNIT columns. That is why they appear blank in the table.

```
PRODUCTID                                  PAID       LABEL         VALUE        UNIT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
F4D58DCE-8EED-40E3-BF4C-07349BEC0A3E                          
F4D58DCE-8EED-40E3-BF4C-07349BEC0A3E                          
F4D58DCE-8EED-40E3-BF4C-07349BEC0A3E                          
F4D58DCE-8EED-40E3-BF4C-07349BEC0A3E                          
F4D58DCE-8EED-40E3-BF4C-07349BEC0A3E                          
F4D58DCE-8EED-40E3-BF4C-07349BEC0A3E                          
F4D58DCE-8EED-40E3-BF4C-07349BEC0A3E                          
F4D58DCE-8EED-40E3-BF4C-07349BEC0A3E                          
F4D58DCE-8EED-40E3-BF4C-07349BEC0A3E                          
F4D58DCE-8EED-40E3-BF4C-07349BEC0A3E                          
F4D58DCE-8EED-40E3-BF4C-07349BEC0A3E                          
F4D58DCE-8EED-40E3-BF4C-07349BEC0A3E                          
F4D58DCE-8EED-40E3-BF4C-07349BEC0A3E                          
F4D58DCE-8EED-40E3-BF4C-07349BEC0A3E                          
F4D58DCE-8EED-40E3-BF4C-07349BEC0A3E                          
F4D58DCE-8EED-40E3-BF4C-07349BEC0A3E                          
F4D58DCE-8EED-40E3-BF4C-07349BEC0A3E                          
F4D58DCE-8EED-40E3-BF4C-07349BEC0A3E                          
F4D58DCE-8EED-40E3-BF4C-07349BEC0A3E                          
F4D58DCE-8EED-40E3-BF4C-07349BEC0A3E                          
F4D58DCE-8EED-40E3-BF4C-07349BEC0A3E                          
ACF57CF7-7206-46F5-A341-16E1B9828DBC                          
ACF57CF7-7206-46F5-A341-16E1B9828DBC                          
ACF57CF7-7206-46F5-A341-16E1B9828DBC                          
ACF57CF7-7206-46F5-A341-16E1B9828DBC                          
ACF57CF7-7206-46F5-A341-16E1B9828DBC                          
ACF57CF7-7206-46F5-A341-16E1B9828DBC                          
ACF57CF7-7206-46F5-A341-16E1B9828DBC                          
ACF57CF7-7206-46F5-A341-16E1B9828DBC                          
ACF57CF7-7206-46F5-A341-16E1B9828DBC                          
ACF57CF7-7206-46F5-A341-16E1B9828DBC                          
ACF57CF7-7206-46F5-A341-16E1B9828DBC                          
ACF57CF7-7206-46F5-A341-16E1B9828DBC                          
ACF57CF7-7206-46F5-A341-16E1B9828DBC                          
ACF57CF7-7206-46F5-A341-16E1B9828DBC                          
ACF57CF7-7206-46F5-A341-16E1B9828DBC                          
ACF57CF7-7206-46F5-A341-16E1B9828DBC                          
ACF57CF7-7206-46F5-A341-16E1B9828DBC                          
ACF57CF7-7206-46F5-A341-16E1B9828DBC                          
ACF57CF7-7206-46F5-A341-16E1B9828DBC                          
ACF57CF7-7206-46F5-A341-16E1B9828DBC                          
ACF57CF7-7206-46F5-A341-16E1B9828DBC                          
95CF8634-DF1C-4E12-9584-56D726F9D3FD                          
95CF8634-DF1C-4E12-9584-56D726F9D3FD                          
95CF8634-DF1C-4E12-9584-56D726F9D3FD                          
95CF8634-DF1C-4E12-9584-56D726F9D3FD                          
95CF8634-DF1C-4E12-9584-56D726F9D3FD                          
95CF8634-DF1C-4E12-9584-56D726F9D3FD                          
95CF8634-DF1C-4E12-9584-56D726F9D3FD                          
95CF8634-DF1C-4E12-9584-56D726F9D3FD                          
95CF8634-DF1C-4E12-9584-56D726F9D3FD                          
95CF8634-DF1C-4E12-9584-56D726F9D3FD                          
95CF8634-DF1C-4E12-9584-56D726F9D3FD                          
95CF8634-DF1C-4E12-9584-56D726F9D3FD                          
95CF8634-DF1C-4E12-9584-56D726F9D3FD                          
95CF8634-DF1C-4E12-9584-56D726F9D3FD                          
95CF8634-DF1C-4E12-9584-56D726F9D3FD                          
95CF8634-DF1C-4E12-9584-56D726F9D3FD                          
95CF8634-DF1C-4E12-9584-56D726F9D3FD                          
95CF8634-DF1C-4E12-9584-56D726F9D3FD                          
95CF8634-DF1C-4E12-9584-56D726F9D3FD                          
95CF8634-DF1C-4E12-9584-56D726F9D3FD                          
95CF8634-DF1C-4E12-9584-56D726F9D3FD                          
C4196FB0-AAE1-4BC4-A6E3-630B90D249C1                          
C4196FB0-AAE1-4BC4-A6E3-630B90D249C1                          
C4196FB0-AAE1-4BC4-A6E3-630B90D249C1                          
C4196FB0-AAE1-4BC4-A6E3-630B90D249C1                          
C4196FB0-AAE1-4BC4-A6E3-630B90D249C1                          
C4196FB0-AAE1-4BC4-A6E3-630B90D249C1                          
C4196FB0-AAE1-4BC4-A6E3-630B90D249C1                          
C4196FB0-AAE1-4BC4-A6E3-630B90D249C1                          
C4196FB0-AAE1-4BC4-A6E3-630B90D249C1                          
C4196FB0-AAE1-4BC4-A6E3-630B90D249C1                          
C4196FB0-AAE1-4BC4-A6E3-630B90D249C1                          
C4196FB0-AAE1-4BC4-A6E3-630B90D249C1                          
C4196FB0-AAE1-4BC4-A6E3-630B90D249C1                          
C4196FB0-AAE1-4BC4-A6E3-630B90D249C1                          
C4196FB0-AAE1-4BC4-A6E3-630B90D249C1                          
C4196FB0-AAE1-4BC4-A6E3-630B90D249C1                          
C4196FB0-AAE1-4BC4-A6E3-630B90D249C1                          
C4196FB0-AAE1-4BC4-A6E3-630B90D249C1                          
C4196FB0-AAE1-4BC4-A6E3-630B90D249C1                          
C4196FB0-AAE1-4BC4-A6E3-630B90D249C1                          
C4196FB0-AAE1-4BC4-A6E3-630B90D249C1                          
A5A24B87-E4E7-4282-8BB1-7413198A7D1A                          
A5A24B87-E4E7-4282-8BB1-7413198A7D1A                          
A5A24B87-E4E7-4282-8BB1-7413198A7D1A                          
A5A24B87-E4E7-4282-8BB1-7413198A7D1A                          
A5A24B87-E4E7-4282-8BB1-7413198A7D1A                          
A5A24B87-E4E7-4282-8BB1-7413198A7D1A                          
A5A24B87-E4E7-4282-8BB1-7413198A7D1A                          
A5A24B87-E4E7-4282-8BB1-7413198A7D1A                          
A5A24B87-E4E7-4282-8BB1-7413198A7D1A                          
A5A24B87-E4E7-4282-8BB1-7413198A7D1A                          
A5A24B87-E4E7-4282-8BB1-7413198A7D1A                          
A5A24B87-E4E7-4282-8BB1-7413198A7D1A                          
A5A24B87-E4E7-4282-8BB1-7413198A7D1A                          
A5A24B87-E4E7-4282-8BB1-7413198A7D1A                          
A5A24B87-E4E7-4282-8BB1-7413198A7D1A                          
A5A24B87-E4E7-4282-8BB1-7413198A7D1A                          
A5A24B87-E4E7-4282-8BB1-7413198A7D1A                          
A5A24B87-E4E7-4282-8BB1-7413198A7D1A                          
A5A24B87-E4E7-4282-8BB1-7413198A7D1A                          
A5A24B87-E4E7-4282-8BB1-7413198A7D1A                          
A5A24B87-E4E7-4282-8BB1-7413198A7D1A                          
7EECE72B-26C5-4306-9706-85E344243122                          
7EECE72B-26C5-4306-9706-85E344243122                          
7EECE72B-26C5-4306-9706-85E344243122                          
7EECE72B-26C5-4306-9706-85E344243122                          
7EECE72B-26C5-4306-9706-85E344243122                          
7EECE72B-26C5-4306-9706-85E344243122                          
7EECE72B-26C5-4306-9706-85E344243122                          
7EECE72B-26C5-4306-9706-85E344243122                          
7EECE72B-26C5-4306-9706-85E344243122                          
7EECE72B-26C5-4306-9706-85E344243122                          
7EECE72B-26C5-4306-9706-85E344243122                          
7EECE72B-26C5-4306-9706-85E344243122                          
7EECE72B-26C5-4306-9706-85E344243122                          
7EECE72B-26C5-4306-9706-85E344243122                          
7EECE72B-26C5-4306-9706-85E344243122                          
7EECE72B-26C5-4306-9706-85E344243122                          
7EECE72B-26C5-4306-9706-85E344243122                          
7EECE72B-26C5-4306-9706-85E344243122                          
7EECE72B-26C5-4306-9706-85E344243122                          
7EECE72B-26C5-4306-9706-85E344243122                          
7EECE72B-26C5-4306-9706-85E344243122                          
60B1AB86-E0EB-41AE-858C-AAD4744FD49C                          
60B1AB86-E0EB-41AE-858C-AAD4744FD49C                          
60B1AB86-E0EB-41AE-858C-AAD4744FD49C                          
60B1AB86-E0EB-41AE-858C-AAD4744FD49C                          
60B1AB86-E0EB-41AE-858C-AAD4744FD49C                          
60B1AB86-E0EB-41AE-858C-AAD4744FD49C                          
60B1AB86-E0EB-41AE-858C-AAD4744FD49C                          
60B1AB86-E0EB-41AE-858C-AAD4744FD49C                          
60B1AB86-E0EB-41AE-858C-AAD4744FD49C                          
60B1AB86-E0EB-41AE-858C-AAD4744FD49C                          
60B1AB86-E0EB-41AE-858C-AAD4744FD49C                          
60B1AB86-E0EB-41AE-858C-AAD4744FD49C                          
60B1AB86-E0EB-41AE-858C-AAD4744FD49C                          
60B1AB86-E0EB-41AE-858C-AAD4744FD49C                          
60B1AB86-E0EB-41AE-858C-AAD4744FD49C                          
60B1AB86-E0EB-41AE-858C-AAD4744FD49C                          
60B1AB86-E0EB-41AE-858C-AAD4744FD49C                          
60B1AB86-E0EB-41AE-858C-AAD4744FD49C                          
60B1AB86-E0EB-41AE-858C-AAD4744FD49C                          
60B1AB86-E0EB-41AE-858C-AAD4744FD49C                          
60B1AB86-E0EB-41AE-858C-AAD4744FD49C                          
44CDDEC6-4889-491B-A896-B719C5B9F3E4                          
44CDDEC6-4889-491B-A896-B719C5B9F3E4                          
44CDDEC6-4889-491B-A896-B719C5B9F3E4                          
44CDDEC6-4889-491B-A896-B719C5B9F3E4                          
44CDDEC6-4889-491B-A896-B719C5B9F3E4                          
44CDDEC6-4889-491B-A896-B719C5B9F3E4                          
44CDDEC6-4889-491B-A896-B719C5B9F3E4                          
44CDDEC6-4889-491B-A896-B719C5B9F3E4                          
44CDDEC6-4889-491B-A896-B719C5B9F3E4                          
44CDDEC6-4889-491B-A896-B719C5B9F3E4                          
44CDDEC6-4889-491B-A896-B719C5B9F3E4                          
44CDDEC6-4889-491B-A896-B719C5B9F3E4                          
44CDDEC6-4889-491B-A896-B719C5B9F3E4                          
44CDDEC6-4889-491B-A896-B719C5B9F3E4                          
44CDDEC6-4889-491B-A896-B719C5B9F3E4                          
44CDDEC6-4889-491B-A896-B719C5B9F3E4                          
44CDDEC6-4889-491B-A896-B719C5B9F3E4                          
44CDDEC6-4889-491B-A896-B719C5B9F3E4                          
44CDDEC6-4889-491B-A896-B719C5B9F3E4                          
44CDDEC6-4889-491B-A896-B719C5B9F3E4                          
44CDDEC6-4889-491B-A896-B719C5B9F3E4                          
3866BBA2-624A-43B7-A04D-DE8ADF5DF739                          
3866BBA2-624A-43B7-A04D-DE8ADF5DF739                          
3866BBA2-624A-43B7-A04D-DE8ADF5DF739                          
3866BBA2-624A-43B7-A04D-DE8ADF5DF739                          
3866BBA2-624A-43B7-A04D-DE8ADF5DF739                          
3866BBA2-624A-43B7-A04D-DE8ADF5DF739                          
3866BBA2-624A-43B7-A04D-DE8ADF5DF739                          
3866BBA2-624A-43B7-A04D-DE8ADF5DF739                          
3866BBA2-624A-43B7-A04D-DE8ADF5DF739                          
3866BBA2-624A-43B7-A04D-DE8ADF5DF739                          
3866BBA2-624A-43B7-A04D-DE8ADF5DF739                          
3866BBA2-624A-43B7-A04D-DE8ADF5DF739                          
3866BBA2-624A-43B7-A04D-DE8ADF5DF739                          
3866BBA2-624A-43B7-A04D-DE8ADF5DF739                          
3866BBA2-624A-43B7-A04D-DE8ADF5DF739                          
3866BBA2-624A-43B7-A04D-DE8ADF5DF739                          
3866BBA2-624A-43B7-A04D-DE8ADF5DF739                          
3866BBA2-624A-43B7-A04D-DE8ADF5DF739                          
3866BBA2-624A-43B7-A04D-DE8ADF5DF739                          
3866BBA2-624A-43B7-A04D-DE8ADF5DF739                          
3866BBA2-624A-43B7-A04D-DE8ADF5DF739                          
AA0A3639-2A36-4731-BF3F-F278D54A99C8                          
AA0A3639-2A36-4731-BF3F-F278D54A99C8                          
AA0A3639-2A36-4731-BF3F-F278D54A99C8                          
AA0A3639-2A36-4731-BF3F-F278D54A99C8                          
AA0A3639-2A36-4731-BF3F-F278D54A99C8                          
AA0A3639-2A36-4731-BF3F-F278D54A99C8                          
AA0A3639-2A36-4731-BF3F-F278D54A99C8                          
AA0A3639-2A36-4731-BF3F-F278D54A99C8                          
AA0A3639-2A36-4731-BF3F-F278D54A99C8                          
AA0A3639-2A36-4731-BF3F-F278D54A99C8                          
AA0A3639-2A36-4731-BF3F-F278D54A99C8                          
AA0A3639-2A36-4731-BF3F-F278D54A99C8                          
AA0A3639-2A36-4731-BF3F-F278D54A99C8                          
AA0A3639-2A36-4731-BF3F-F278D54A99C8                          
AA0A3639-2A36-4731-BF3F-F278D54A99C8                          
AA0A3639-2A36-4731-BF3F-F278D54A99C8                          
AA0A3639-2A36-4731-BF3F-F278D54A99C8                          
AA0A3639-2A36-4731-BF3F-F278D54A99C8                          
AA0A3639-2A36-4731-BF3F-F278D54A99C8                          
AA0A3639-2A36-4731-BF3F-F278D54A99C8                          
AA0A3639-2A36-4731-BF3F-F278D54A99C8
```

Comment: Can you give the database structure?

Comment: I have added the temp table #attributes where the data is pulled from.

Comment: This ID list isn't helping, you might want to consider replacing this with the desired structure of the created table.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. That is not a list but a table with values populated in the ProductID column but no values in the other columns. That is why they are blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclude `ProductID` from the UNPIVOT column list and, correspondingly, exclude all `ProductID*` columns from the PIVOT column list. Also, include `ProductID` in the subquery's SELECT:

```
select *
      from
      (
        select [ProductID], col + cast(rn as varchar(10)) new_col, val
        from 
        (
          select 
          Cast(PAID as NVarchar(3072)) PAID
          ,Cast (ProductID as NVarchar(3072)) ProductID
           ,Cast (Label  as NVarchar(3072)) Label
           ,Cast (Value as NVarchar(3072)) Value
           ,Cast (unit as NVarchar(3072))  unit  
            ,row_number() over(partition by ProductID order by ProductID) rn
          from #Attributes
        ) x
        unpivot
        (
          val
          for col in ([ProductID],[PAID],[Label],[Value],[unit])
        ) u
      ) x1
      pivot
      (
        max(val)
        for new_col in
          ([ProductID1],[PAID1],[Label1],[Value1],[unit1],
           [ProductID2],[PAID2],[Label2],[Value2],[unit2],
           [ProductID3],[PAID3],[Label3],[Value3],[unit3],
           [ProductID4],[PAID4],[Label4],[Value4],[unit4],
           [ProductID5],[PAID5],[Label5],[Value5],[unit5],
           [ProductID6],[PAID6],[Label6],[Value6],[unit6],
           [ProductID7],[PAID7],[Label7],[Value7],[unit7],
           [ProductID8],[PAID8],[Label8],[Value8],[unit8],
           [ProductID9],[PAID9],[Label9],[Value9],[unit9],
           [ProductID10],[PAID10],[Label10],[Value10],[unit10],
           [ProductID11],[PAID11],[Label11],[Value11],[unit11],
           [ProductID12],[PAID12],[Label12],[Value12],[unit12],
           [ProductID13],[PAID13],[Label13],[Value13],[unit13],
           [ProductID14],[PAID14],[Label14],[Value14],[unit14],
           [ProductID15],[PAID15],[Label15],[Value15],[unit15],
           [ProductID16],[PAID16],[Label16],[Value16],[unit16],
           [ProductID17],[PAID17],[Label17],[Value17],[unit17],
           [ProductID18],[PAID18],[Label18],[Value18],[unit18],
           [ProductID19],[PAID19],[Label19],[Value19],[unit19],
           [ProductID20],[PAID20],[Label20],[Value20],[unit20],
           [ProductID21],[PAID21],[Label21],[Value21],[unit21])
      ) p
```

---

UPDATE: Explanation for the above solution.

In your query, the `x` subquery returns data like this:

```
ProductID  PAID   Label   Value   unit   rn
---------  -----  ------  ------  -----  ---
A          ...    ...     ...     ...    1
A          ...    ...     ...     ...    2
...        ...    ...     ...     ...    ...
B          ...    ...     ...     ...    1
...        ...    ...     ...     ...    ...
```

The `UNPIVOT` clause transforms them like so:

```
rn   col        val
---  ---------  -----
1    ProductID  A
1    PAID       ...
1    Label      ...
1    Value      ...
1    unit       ...
2    ProductID  A
2    PAID       ...
2    Label      ...
2    Value      ...
2    unit       ...
...  ...        ...
1    ProductID  B
1    PAID       ...
1    Label      ...
1    Value      ...
1    unit       ...
```

And the SELECT clause concatenates the first two columns to return the following:

```
new_col     val
----------  -----
ProductID1  A
PAID1       ...
Label1      ...
Value1      ...
unit1       ...
ProductID2  A
PAID2       ...
Label2      ...
Value2      ...
unit2       ...
...         ...
ProductID1  B
PAID1       ...
Label1      ...
Value1      ...
unit1       ...
...         ...
```

That is the rowset that is ultimately being pivoted. Note that at this point there is no way for SQL Server to tell product `A`'s attributes from those of product `B`. The PIVOT clause acts similar to GROUP BY, collapsing all values with identical `new_col` values into one by applying `MAX()` to them. If there was a non-pivoted column, rows would be split into groups based on the values in that column. But there's no one in the above rowset and, as a result, *all* the rows are collapsed into one.

What you need instead is to make your final-but-one rowset look something like this:

```
ProductID  new_col  val
---------  -------  -----
A          PAID1    ...
A          Label1   ...
A          Value1   ...
A          unit1    ...
A          PAID2    ...
A          Label2   ...
A          Value2   ...
A          unit2    ...
...        ...      ...
B          PAID1    ...
B          Label1   ...
B          Value1   ...
B          unit1    ...
...        ...      ...
```

That is, the `ProductID` column allows SQL Server to distinguish between `PAID1` belonging to product `A` and that belonging to `B`.

To obtain that rowset, you just need to exclude `ProductID` from the `UNPIVOT` clause and pull it alongside the unpivoted columns instead. And since `ProductID` is excluded from the UNPIVOT column list, all the `ProductID1`, `ProductID2` etc. should also be excluded from the PIVOT one, which you can see done in the query above.

Comment: Could you please explain why you need to do that please? From other examples I have seen, it is possible to have the ProductID in there. but is there a reason why I need to remove it in my case?

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I have tried unsuccessfully to get this question answered before now. Thank you. :)